# POST xml from iPhone to PHP

Tags: php, iphone, post

I am working on one project in which I am preparing API to interact with server from iPhone.

I have created API with POST parameter `xmlrequest` and in that parameter, I am passing xml content.

Everything is working correctly, except, when in xml content if any special character comes, it cuts off on server side.

My question is should I apply any header/content type on both sides, if yes, Can I get example ?

EDIT:

It is an issue of special character, in xml content I tried to replace "&" with "and" and it worked, but when I try to replace "&" with "&", it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In HTTP, GET- and POST- parameters are seperated with the special characters `?`, `&` and `=`. I'm sure you already have seen things like that in URLS: `example.com?foo=bar&meow=woof`

Your server will parse the query-string, and it assumes that everytime a `&` appears, it's a new parameter. So, in order to pass such a special character, you first need to URL-encode it (on the iPhone-side). For example, the space-character, URL-encoded, would be `%20`.

You can then decode the URL-encoded string on server side using `urldecode()` and `rawurldecode()`.

Comment: would getting raw data on php side like $xml = file_get_contents('php://input'); work?

Comment: You could access the raw query-string with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` but I don't recommend to do so. What if you'd need to pass an additional parameter to the URL later on? You wouldn't be able to make a difference from the XML containing a `&` to the URL-parameters. Encoding and decoding is really simple, and there are already functions for that - so why not do so?

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the problem areas in [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) tags, or perhaps implement [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), etc if the XML is being generated/handled by the PHP. There is a fair bit on the subject [out there](http://minutillo.com/steve/weblog/2004/6/17/php-xml-and-character-encodings-a-tale-of-sadness-rage-and-data-loss/).

Can you elaborate

> it cuts off on server side.

Comment: Thanks Ergo, for your reply. it cuts off on server side, by means, I printed _POST array on server side, but it cuts off content when it found "&" in the content.

Comment: You need to make sure that characters in the XML are encoded, '&' should appear as '&amp;' in the XML. Alternatively, if PHP recieves the content as $xml, try echo htmlentities($xml)

Comment: but I printed $_POST['xmlrequest'] in PHP, it gave me xml content only upto "&" after that content was cut off.

Comment: Yes, a single '&' is interpreted differently to its character reference '&amp;'. Replacing '&' with '&amp;' (and similar characters) will resolve the issue, '&amp;' is the char ref for '&'...

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references. " The XML specification defines five "predefined entities" representing special characters, and requires that all XML processors honor them."

Comment: I passed xmlrequest=<Test><comment>Testing &amp; sign</comment></Test>, but on server side, it gives <Test><comment>Testing . I did replacing & with &amp;, but still the same issue

Comment: Do I need to say PHP, that in xmlrequest, there will be xml content. If yes, how can I define that header in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Andre_roesti, He gave me right direction. Here is my solution to encode special characters which are to be passed into POST method.

iPhone side:

```
@interface NSString (URLEncode)
-(NSString *)urlEncode;
@end

@implementation NSString (URLEncode)
-(NSString *)urlEncode{
  return [(NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(NULL, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, CFSTR("￼=,!$&'()*+;@?\n\"<>#\t :/"),kCFStringEncodingUTF8) autorelease];
}
@end
```

PHP side:

I made  `$xmlrequest = html_entity_decode($_POST['xmlrequest']);`